# Which spring security version is compatible with Spring3.0.4?

Tags: eclipse, spring, security, compatibility

I am new to Spring framework and learning spring security now-a-days.

I am using:
**Eclipse 3.3 (Europa)**
**Tomcat 5.5**
**Spring 3.0.4**
**Java 1.6**

I am developing just a *HelloWorld* application. There is a controller class and a
dispatcher-servlet.xml which have no problem with me absolutely.

*WHAT MY PROBLEM IS:*
When I run the project just to call the **index.jsp** present in <welcome-file>
of web.xml file it works **fine**

***BUT*** when I add the following in my web.xml file to achieve spring security:

After `<servlet>,<servlet-mapping>,<context-param> and <listener>`

```
  <filter>  
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
  </filter>  
  <filter-mapping>  
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
  </filter-mapping>
```

NOW if I run it output in browser is:

The requested resource () is not available.

**where is the problem ?**

What I think that there might be some compatibility issues.
BECAUSE: If you visit the <http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/downloads.html>

The download options are:
Spring Security **3.1.0** for Spring **3.0.6** AND
Spring Security **3.0.7** for Spring **3.0.6** AND
Spring Security **2.0.7** for Spring **2.0 and 2.5**

But I am using Spring3.0.4. So WHAT TO USE?
In this project I have included the following jar files:

spring-security-acl-2.0.7
spring-security-cas-client-2.0.7
spring-security-core-2.0.7
spring-security-openid-2.0.7

If compatibility is an issue, then please help me which configurations and Spring
Security version to use with my eclipse and Tomcat versions?

AND one final thing:
in web.xml, in `<context-param>` my code:

```
 <param-value>  
   /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml  
 </param-value>
```

Is This the correct way?

Comment: If you're developing a HelloWorld application, why are you using old, outdated versions of the framework? Why not just use the latest and greatest so that you get the best support and security? If I were starting anew, I'd download Spring 3.1 and Spring Security 3.0.6.

Comment: If you are working with Spring 3.04, use Spring Security 3.04 to be sure there will be not any compatibility issue. 3.04 is available out there.

Comment: Just to say that Spring Security 3.1.0 is also available. As jmort said - if you have the choice, why not jump to the latest versions of given software and forget the worries of compatibilty?